2000s movie about a guy whose girlfriend dies in a car accident with a truck in a mountain
The film is about a couple that in a scene are hanging out together with some other friends of theirs in a mountain or something like that.  The girlfriend had some type of career plan that differed from what the boyfriend wanted or something similar, the girlfriend drives away but crashes with a big truck and dies.
Later, the boyfriend wakes up (from what seemed to be a nightmare) and the girlfriend is alive next to him saying that everything is okay and that she didn't die in the accident.
She doesn't follow the career plan she wanted to follow, and she ends up doing cheap work in her field. (it was photography or painting or something like that)  However, the guy ends up cheating on her somehow.
At the end they are back at the mountain with their friends but this time the guy tells the girlfriend to go after her career plan, and he drives away but ends up crashing into the same big truck as in the beginning.
It was probably released after 2000 and before 2012. 

Holy wall of text Batman!

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What time period was it about? What country was it likely from? What language? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes, recognisable actors or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

This sounds like The Butterfly Effect 2
At the beginning: 

As the four friends drive back to the city there's an accident with a
  semi-truck

In the middle:

... he awakens in a new timeline where Julie is living happily with him. However, in this reality, Nick's life is ruined when he is fired. 

...

In this reality ...  he and Julie have split up and he is living the bachelor lifestyle

At the end:

Nick transports himself to the scene from the start of the movie, hoping to finally fix everything ... [Julie] speeds away in his car. Fearing a similar accident as the original, Nick speeds after her, but ends up facing an oncoming vehicle himself. He opts to save Julie rather than himself and drives off the cliff.


Oh my god, they made a sequel...
